# project build causes null pointer exception at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.ClasspathJrt.addRequired(ClasspathJrt.java:326)

Tags: eclipse, dynamic, build, project

opened a new dynamic eclipse project and when i cleaned it .got the following error in error log
didn't include any java code in it yet.

using jre 14 with --release option
tomcat 9
eclipse version 2019-03 EE

full stack trace

java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.ClasspathJrt.addRequired(ClasspathJrt.java:326)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.ClasspathJrt.selectModules(ClasspathJrt.java:320)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.ClasspathJrtWithReleaseOption.getModuleNames(ClasspathJrtWithReleaseOption.java:347)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.NameEnvironment.collectModuleEntries(NameEnvironment.java:397)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.NameEnvironment.computeClasspathLocations(NameEnvironment.java:319)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.NameEnvironment.(NameEnvironment.java:62)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.initializeBuilder(JavaBuilder.java:629)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.clean(JavaBuilder.java:301)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:835)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:220)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:263)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:316)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:319)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:278)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:468)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:574)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2295)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:548)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:116)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.dialogs.CleanDialog.doClean(CleanDialog.java:460)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.dialogs.CleanDialog$1.runInWorkspace(CleanDialog.java:207)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)

how should i resolve above error

Comment: Looks like [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=546338) fixed in newer versions of Eclipse

Comment: JRE 14 came out a year after Eclipse 2019-03. You should update to a newer Eclipse.

Comment: how to know in which version of eclipse this gets resolved ? am a new bee

Comment: @poornima According to the bug report, it has been fixed 6 releases ago: `Target Milestone: 4.13`. Please make sure the software you are using is up to date before asking.

Comment: You should always use the latest Eclipse release, currently 2021-03